# Permanently change zsh environment variable on macOS Big Sur?

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, script, zsh

I tried to customize the ZSH terminal shell (e.g. prompt, auto-completion behavior) by editing the ZSH files, but failed.
I have tried both the following, and none worked:

1. Edit `~/.zshrc`:
   When I tried to edit the (blank) file (even under the sudo command), I got the following error message: **".zshrc" E166: Can't open linked file for writing** (similar problem happens when trying on `.zshenv`.
2. Edit `/etc/zshrc`:
   This worked, until the computer restarted and resets the file.

**What is the correct way to deal with this?**

<sub>N.B.: I'm running macOS Big Sur 11.6.</sub>

Comment: Either chmod the file u+w or use sudo?

Comment: It sounds like you have ~/.zshrc symlinked to something that -- for one reason or another -- cannot be edited. What does `ls -l ~/.zshrc` show?

Comment: Why do you think you need to use sudo to edit a file in your own $HOME?

Answer (score 1):

Undo whatever changes you made to **/etc/zshrc**, then forget that this file exists.  You should be leaving that file alone.

Put your changes in **$HOME/.zshrc**.  This will usually work, `zsh` should read that file on startup whenever the shell is an interactive one (see `man zsh`).  Note that `zsh` reads that file regardless of whether or not it is a login shell, so it will be interpreted on every shell invocation.

Forget that `sudo` exists.

Comment: RE: "Forget that `sudo` exists." --  That's not very practical as there are many things that one might need to do that require the use of `sudo`

Comment: @user3439894 The intention there was clearly to say "Forget that `sudo` exists [when doing this task]"

Comment: @marc-wilson thanks for your reply. And that was indeed the first thing that I did.
However, like I said:

When I tried to edit the (blank) file (even under the sudo command), I got the following error message: **".zshrc" E166: Can't open linked file for writing** (similar problem happens when trying on `.zshenv`.

That was why I post here to start with. 

Do you have any idea why that happened? Thanks!

Comment: Hey! So, it seems that the problem is `~/.zshrc` was a symlink, and simply by removing it via `sudo rm ~/.zshrc` and recreating it does the job! Thanks to [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1071656/etc-resolv-conf-e166-cant-open-linked-file-for-writing)...

Comment: Please don't tell us you used sudo when you edited the file...